# QuickSort function in Java is giving a StackOverflow

Tags: java, quicksort

I know this isn't really  a bug-testing place, but I've been trying to spot my error in my java quicksort for hours, and I can't see it, so if anyone can point it out to me I'd be very very grateful.

Here's example:

```
     public class QuickSort {
    public static int partition(int[] a, int start, int end) {

        int piv = a[end];
        int iLeft = start;
        int iRight = end;
        while (iLeft < iRight) {
            while (a[iLeft] < piv) {
                iLeft++;
            }
            while (a[iRight] >= piv) {
                iRight--;
                if (iRight == iLeft) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (iLeft < iRight) {
                int val = a[iLeft];
                a[iLeft] = a[iRight];
                a[iRight] = val;
            }

        }
        return iRight;
    }

    public static int[] Sort(int[] a, int start, int end) {
        if (a.length < 2) {
            return a;
        } else {
            int Next_Mid = partition(a, start, end);
            Sort(a, start, Next_Mid);
            Sort(a, Next_Mid + 1, end);
            return a;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] c = new int[] { 1, 10, 2, 9, 3, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5 };
        Sort(c, 0, c.length - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know there is an error?  Have you seen the error?  When does it occur?

Comment: Pasting / explaining the bug you are seeing would be helpful...

Answer (score 4):

Since your `Sort` method never makes a new sub-array for `a`, your exit condition is wrong: if `a` starts with 10 elements, it would always have ten elements, so your recursion will never end.

You need to check if the start and the end indexes are two or less positions apart:

```
if (end-start < 2) {
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is obvious:

```
public static int[] Sort(int[] a, int start, int end) {
  if (a.length < 2) {
    return a;
  } else {
    int Next_Mid = partition(a, start, end);
    Sort(a, start, Next_Mid);
    Sort(a, Next_Mid + 1, end);
    return a;
  }
}
```

Recursion can only end if length of the array is < 2, and yet you pass the **same** array all the time.

You probably want to look for `end-start` or something.